# MobileFirst Container Image doesn't show runtimes in Operations Console

Tags: ssh, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am using the evaluation container image for Bluemix. I have downloaded the image, and configured all the .properties files for scripts. Then pushed the image. I have used Clouding as the DB.

When I start the container, I see no runtimes displayed in Operation Console. When I open Cloudant console, I can see only one DB created with the name of the project I chose to deploy. There is no DB for administration.

I am not able to check the logs, it throws an error when I chose to create a volume in startsrver script. I am not able to login using SSH as well although I pasted the SSH public key file in usr/ssh before pushing.

Comment: What do you mean by downloaded the "evaluation container image"? You mean you actually created your own image from scratch, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard flow to have all up running is this:

```
./installcontainercli.sh
./initenv.sh args/initenv.properties
./prepareserverdbs.sh args/prepareserverdbs.properties
#this step you will repeat for each runtime you have to install.
./prepareserverdbs.sh args/prepareserverdbs.InvokingAdapterProcedures.properties
#steps to be repeated for deploys
./prepareserver.sh args/prepareserver.properties
./startserver.sh args/startserver.properties
```

The tricky here is that in the args/prepareserverdbs.properties the runtime property is commented.

At the file  args/prepareserverdbs.InvokingAdapterProcedures.properties is the same at the file args/prepareserverdbs.properties, it is not commented.

Said that first you run:

```
./prepareserverdbs.sh args/prepareserverdbs.properties
```

then you run the following command to to create the runtime DB:

```
./prepareserverdbs.sh args/prepareserverdbs.InvokingAdapterProcedures.properties
```

After that, you follow with the deploy sequence:

```
#steps to be repeated for deploys

./prepareserver.sh args/prepareserver.properties

./startserver.sh args/startserver.properties
```

Details at: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/bluemix/run-foundation-on-bluemix/

Example of the app properties:

```
#   Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 
#   5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
#   US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
#   disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.  

################################################################################################################################################
#  This file defines the various properties that needs to be provided for running the prepareserverdbs.sh script

#  Run prepareserverdbs.sh script to configure the management and runtime databases for the MobileFirst Platform projects. 

#  The Bluemix DB service type. The value can be either sqldb or cloudantNoSQLDB
DB_TYPE=cloudantNoSQLDB

#  Bluemix DB service instance name
DB_SRV_NAME=CloudantDB

#  Bluemix database service plan to create the service instance. For SQL DB, the accepted values are sqldb_small, sqldb_free, sqldb_premium.
#  For Cloudant DB, the accepted value is Shared
DB_SRV_PLAN=Shared

#  Bluemix application name to bind the DB service instance
APP_NAME=<your app name>

#  (Optional) The name of the runtime project to be deployed on MFPF server. Specified only for configuring runtime database
RUNTIME_NAME=FormBasedAuth 

#  (Optional) Database Schema Name. Defaults to WLADMIN for admin database and runtime name for runtime database
#SCHEMA_NAME=
```

Comment: On the sample provided above prepareserverdbs.InvokingAdapterProcedures.properties is the file a created prepare the DB for the app from this sample: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/

Feel free to use the name you want.. :)

Comment: Thank you Cesar. However, this is the sequence I followed. I could deploy the project, and the DB for the project was created on Cloudant. But the WL_ADMIN DB is not created, and thus no runtimes are shown in the Operations Console.

Same problem is mentioned here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/r_ts_no_runtimes_listed.html

However, I am not able to check the logs to know what the problem is. This is related to the SSH problem.

Comment: You can make the ssh to work by adding your ssh keys "key."and "key.pub"at the ssh folder. at the same level of the _args_ folder. 
In my case the folder structure is:
_scripts\args\_
_scripts\ssh\id_rsa_
_scripts\ssh\id_rsa.pub_

At the _args\startserver.properties_, I leave the SSH_KEY commented.

To access the image I use:
ssh -i ./id_rsa root@<IP SERVER>

Comment: The file structure:  
scripts\args  ; 
scripts\ssh\id_rsa  ; 
scripts\ssh\id_rsa.pub  ;

Comment: The first time I tried to prepare my image, the ADMIN DB was not created also, then I realised that I was running ./prepareserverdbs.sh args/prepareserverdbs.properties with the runtime with RUNTIME_NAME uncommented. This was indicating to the script to create the app db not the admin db. When I commented it creates the admin DB. And things started to work as expected. :)

Comment: The file structure:  (fixed - scripts\user\ssh)
scripts\args  ; 
scripts\usr\ssh\id_rsa  ; 
scripts\usr\ssh\id_rsa.pub  ;

Comment: Thank you @Cesar, the trick to run createserdb with runtime commented, then run it again with it uncommented did the trick.

I could as well connect on SSH using root user.

Thank you again :)

Comment: @cesar Specify the name of your Bluemix application. Which name should I provide here. I provided name of my MFP project war file. I am getting The Bluemix application test was not found. Can you please help me

Comment: The name should be of of your bluemix application, a cloud foundry app you create as the holder of the services you will create to use the docker containers.  For example a "java runtime" or "nodeJS", your server will be in the docker container. This application works as point for binding the server, to allow than to be shared with your container.  Your create this app by your dashboard/via command line on bluemix. 

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cfapps/index.html